# поиск по массиву по searchbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Такая проблема, если я добавляю в массив несколько значений (1-5), то поиск работает идеально, но если в массив добавить скажем 15 значение, то вылетает вот такая ошибка

```
    2015-05-07 12:24:55.852 gfhfgh[5662:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.138/UITableView.m:5439
2015-05-07 12:24:55.860 gfhfgh[5662:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e2fdf83 0x38aaeccf 0x2e2fde5d 0x2ecabd5b 0x30c86dff 0xf00b9 0x30c4d8f7 0x30bf4c27 0x30be7c5d 0x30be7ba3 0x30bf41cd 0x30b3a167 0x30be71eb 0x30bc86fd 0x30bc848d 0x30bc9bf5 0x30c7dcc5 0x30d0c011 0x30c36109 0x30d0abcd 0x30d0aaaf 0x30b50037 0x30b4ffd7 0x30b4ffb1 0x30b3b717 0x30b3acfd 0x30b37805 0x30c16f15 0x30d0a91f 0x30b99127 0x30b993e7 0x30c15c17 0x30e9e579 0x30ca0fed 0x30b4c4e3 0x30ef3aed 0x30b13353 0x30b11a9b 0x30b4ad49 0x30b4a66f 0x30b1f8cd 0x30b1df77 0x2e2c920b 0x2e2c86db 0x2e2c6ecf 0x2e231ebf 0x2e231ca3 0x33137663 0x30b7e14d 0xfa1a9 0x38fbbab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
--
```

В чем проблема?
Сам код

```
    #import "StreetTableViewController.h"
@interface StreetTableViewController () 
//@interface StreetTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate>
// the items to be searched

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *items;

// the current search results
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *searchResults;

@end

@implementation StreetTableViewController

#pragma mark - NSCoding

// set some initial searchable items
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        _items
        = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"bar", @"foo", @"quux",/* @"Академика крылова ул. ст. м. Черная речка",*/
           @"Академика Павлова ул. д.5",
           @"Бабушкина ул. д.9",
          /* @"Богатырский пр. д.15", @"Большая Зеленая ул. д.12",*/
           @"Большая конюшенная ул. д.10",
          /* @"Большевиков пр. д.3к.1",
           @"Бутлерова ул., 42",*/
         @"Вознесенский пр. д.37",
          /* @"Вознесенский пр. д.37",
           @"Витебский пр. д.101",
           @"Гражданский пр. д.114 к.1",*/
           @"Гапсальская ул. д.1",
           @"Гороховая ул. д.45",
           @"Дыбенко ул. д.18",
 nil];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayDelegate

// register a cell reuse identifier for the search results table view
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
 didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
      forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"];
}

// perform the search
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    NSPredicate *predicate
    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self beginswith [c] %@", searchString];
    NSArray *searchResults
    = [[self items] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [self setSearchResults:searchResults];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

// check if displaying search results
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        return [[self searchResults] count];
    } else {
        return [[self items] count];
    }
}

// check if displaying search results
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell
        = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"
                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
        id item = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:item];
        return cell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *cell
        = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"
                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
        id item = [[self items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:item];
        return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

// manually perform detail segue after selecting a search result
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:cell];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController

/* prepare for detail scene segue
 called after cell selection in the master and
 search results table views */
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;

    id item = nil;
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath
        = [[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
        item = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath
        = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
        item = [[self items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }

    UIViewController *detail
    = (UIViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    [[detail navigationItem] setTitle:item];
}
@end
```

Comment: Наверно вот эта строка не сработала: [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
      forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"]; Я бы перенес ее в viewDidLoad.

Comment: @stosha но у меня нет viewDidLoad в этом файле....или я чего то не понимаю

Comment: Надо добавить метод - (void) viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad];  [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"]; }  Этот метод вызывается автоматически при первой загрузке UIViewController.

Comment: Я понял что имеется ввиду ошибка транслятора. Ругается на tableView? Значит self.tableView надо вместо просто tableView. tableView объявлено как свойство в UITableViewController. Я же так понимаю что у тебя UITableViewController.

Comment: @stosha Спасибо, немного подправил и заработало - (void) viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad]; [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"]; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй перенести

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
      forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"];
```

в метод

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"]; 
}
```

если нет такого метода, то надо создать.